Read_csv() in Pandas doesn't recognize one of its arguments: date_format
I have a Jupyter notebook that has worked in the past. Recently however (without upgrading anything) I have run into this problem: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'date_format'
The cell in question looks like this:
SYMH = pd.read_csv('2012-11-13_SYMH.txt', delimiter='\s+', parse_dates=['DATE', 'TIME'], date_format=['%Y-%m-%d', '%H:%M:%S.%f'])
SYMH['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(SYMH['DATE']+' '+SYMH['TIME'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
SYMH.drop(['DATE', 'TIME'], axis=1, inplace=True)

AE = pd.read_csv('2012-11-13_AE.txt', delimiter='\s+', parse_dates=['DATE', 'TIME'], date_format=['%Y-%m-%d', '%H:%M:%S.%f'])
AE['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(AE['DATE']+' '+AE['TIME'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
AE.drop(['DATE', 'TIME'], axis=1, inplace=True)

And the error log output looks like this:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 SYMH = pd.read_csv('2012-11-13_SYMH.txt', delimiter='\s+', parse_dates=['DATE', 'TIME'], date_format=['%Y-%m-%d', '%H:%M:%S.%f'])
      2 SYMH['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(SYMH['DATE']+' '+SYMH['TIME'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
      3 SYMH.drop(['DATE', 'TIME'], axis=1, inplace=True)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/solarwind/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:211, in deprecate_kwarg.<locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    209     else:
    210         kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 211 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/solarwind/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:331, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    325 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    326     warnings.warn(
    327         msg.format(arguments=_format_argument_list(allow_args)),
    328         FutureWarning,
    329         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
    330     )
--> 331 return func(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'date_format'

Does the line "deprecate_kwarg.<locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)" mean that this is a depreciated keyword? The documentation on the Pandas website specifically lists it as a usable keyword.
I have tried to resolve this by restarting my kernel, my IDE, trying a different interpreter, upgrading Pandas with pip, and nothing has worked. I will note that this has happened in the past but restarting the kernel usually fixes it. This time restarting it has no effect.

What version of pandas are you using? This option was added in 2.0.0.

What do you get from pd.__version__?

According to pip and my interpreter, 2.2.2, but according to the jupyter notebook, 1.5.x which really surprised me. Not sure why both would be different. Fixing this discrepancy solves it.

This is probably because the version of Pandas your notebook is using is <2.0. Check this by running pd.__version__ in a notebook cell. In my case, it showed 1.5.6 despite running pip install pandas -U in the terminal. If you are using Anaconda, like in my case, update it directly from the Anaconda package manager in your IDE.

Just to emphasize, once you installed Anaconda that became your primary package manager and to keep your environments robust and portable you should endeavor to only use Anaconda/conda to update things. In other words, only ever use pip from now on in cases where there is no conda recipe. Your last sentence shows you are starting to get this. (But you shouldn't have been running pip in the terminal and expecting Jupyter to use that.) You can use the magic install commands in Jupyter to insure the installations occur in the proper environment, too. For example when it wasn't working, ...

 you could gave run in the notebook where you wanted the newer version of Pandas, %conda install conda-forge::pandas , based on here, and using the magic install commands present in modern Jupyter. See more about the modern magic install commands here, and stick with %conda install as much as possible where you are working.
